# Как удалить дубликаты строк при записи в файл?

Tags: python, сортировка

```
data = response.json()
with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
    for item in data['result']['List']:
        if item.get("host"):
             file.write(f'{item.get("host")}\n')
```

Я немного неправильно назвал заголовок. Нужно в файле удалить дубли, а не во время выполнения скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

например сначала накопить слова в списке, потом записать только

```
data = response.json()
dublicates = set()
with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
    for item in data['result']['List']:
        line = item.get("host")
        if item.get("host") and line not in dublicates:
             dublicates.add(line);
             file.write(f'{line}\n')
```

Comment: а  если в файле удалять дубликаты, а не в скрипте?

Comment: значит считать файл, удалить в считанных данных и перезаписать файл - файлы удобно ДОПИСЫВАТЬ и ОБРЕЗАТЬ, но если надо менять что-то в середине файла, то файл надо менять весь

Comment: у меня 20 результатов выводит, там накапливать нечего. нужно просто записать в файл, потом в этом файле удалить лишние строки

Comment: еще раз - из файла вы ничего удалить не сможете из начала или середины, только перезапись файла - ну как вы себе представляете процесс удаления какого-то блока внутри файла?

Comment: а весь файл можно?

Comment: весь файл и нужно - если надо менять что-то в начале или середине файла (а не просто отрезать часть файла кратного размеру кластера на диске), то только считать, обработать и записать заново

Comment: Да, так и хотел. Можете показать пример?

Comment: так вроде я и привел пример

Comment: Попробую применить. Извеняюсь за нубство